# static reference on a non-static object error in eclipse

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Eclipse is giving me the static referencing a non-static object error when I try to call `isOdd()` from `Number.java` but since `isOdd()` doesn't contain any arguments, I can't call the outside method as I usually would.

**NumberAnalyzer.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.NextAction;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class NumberAnalyzer
{
private ArrayList<Number> list;

public NumberAnalyzer()
{

}

public NumberAnalyzer(String numbers)
{
    list = new ArrayList<Number>();
    String nums = numbers;
    Scanner chopper = new Scanner(nums);
    while(chopper.hasNext()){
        int num = chopper.nextInt();
        list.add(new Number(num));
    }
    chopper.close();
    System.out.println(list);
}

public void setList(String numbers)
{
    list = new ArrayList<Number>();
    String nums = numbers;
    Scanner chopper = new Scanner(nums);
    while(chopper.hasNext()){
        int num = chopper.nextInt();
        list.add(new Number(num));
    }
    chopper.close();

}

public int countOdds()
{
  int oddCount=0;
  for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
      if(Number.isOdd()== true){
          oddCount++;
      }
  }
  return oddCount;
}

public int countEvens()
{
  int evenCount=0;



  return evenCount;
}

public int countPerfects()
{
    int perfectCount=0;



  return perfectCount;
}

public String toString( )
{
    return "";
}
}
```

**Number.java**

```
public class Number
{
private Integer number;

public Number()
{


}

public Number(int num)
{
    number = num;
}

public void setNumber(int num)
{
    number = num;
}

public int getNumber()
{
    return number;
}   

public boolean isOdd()
{
    if(number%2==0){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean isPerfect()
{
    int total=0;
    for(int i = 1; i < number; i++){
        if(number%i==0){
            total+= i;
        }
    }


    return (number==total);
}   

public String toString( )
{
    String output = getNumber() + "\n" + getNumber()+ "isOdd == " + isOdd() + "\n" + getNumber()+ "isPerfect==" + isPerfect()+ "\n\n";
    return output;
}
}
```

**runner class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Lab16b
{
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    NumberAnalyzer test = new NumberAnalyzer("5 12 9 6 1 4 8 6");
    out.println(test);
    out.println("odd count = "+test.countOdds());
    out.println("even count = "+test.countEvens());
    out.println("perfect count = "+test.countPerfects()+"\n\n\n");


    //add more test cases


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have `list` global. Just do

```
  for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
          if(list.get(i).isOdd()){
              oddCount++;
          }
      }
```

That way you're actually getting a `Number` from `list` and can call the `isOdd()` method.

Note that you don't need the `== true` check.

Comment: AH!!! You're very right, that got rid of the red underline! I've never dealt with classes set up quite like this before

Comment: why wouldn't I need the `== true` check on it? If I modified the `Number` class the right way, I'd understand but I didn't mod it

Comment: `isOdd()` returns `boolean`. An if statement evaluates a `boolean` expression, which is always either `true` or `false`. Doing just `isOdd()` is the same as doing `isOdd() == true` since `true == true`.

Answer (score 1):

`Number.isOdd` applys to a `Number` instance. As your `for` loop is covering the range of indices for the `List` (`list`) of `Numbers`, you can replace

```
if (Number.isOdd() == true) {
```

with

```
if (list.get(i).isOdd() == true) {
```

or better

```
if (list.get(i).isOdd()) {
```